# Copy object with value on swift

Tags: swift

I have a class Client which map on Core Data.

```
class Client: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged var lastName: String?
    @NSManaged var age: Int?
```

I tried to implement NSCopy, I wrote this code

```
class Client: NSManagedObject, NSCopying {
    @NSManaged var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged var lastName: String?
    @NSManaged var age: Int?

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int) {
        self.firstName = firstName?
        self.lastName = lastName?
        self.age = age?
    }

    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        let copy = Person(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, age: age)
        return copy
    }
}
```

But I get an error from xcode

> Type 'Client' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'

Is there something missing or is there another solution beside structures to copy a client object with value?

Comment: Are you still getting that same error after adding `NSCopying` and the `copy(with:)` method?

Comment: Yes, I got the error when I wrote the hole code I posted

Comment: This won't work anyway, because it's required to use the designated initializer of `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: It worth to mention which version of Swift are you using